# Is it possible to remove default databases and system.indexes in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

1. Is it possible in MongoDB to delete `local` and `admin` databases or to ignore them with PyMongo so they do not show in the output of the script below?
2. Is it possible with PyMongo to ignore or delete `system.indexes` collections so it does not show in the output of the script below?

The following PyMongo code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__ == '__main__':

    db = MongoClient()

    for db_name in db.database_names():
        print "Database name: " + db_name
        for col_name in db[db_name].collection_names():
            print " - Collection name: " + col_name
```

produced the following output:

```
Database name: test
- Collection name: system.indexes
- Collection name: users
Database name: local
- Collection name: startup_log
- Collection name: system.indexes
Database name: admin
```

Comment: The test database is save to remove. Removing local and admin might give you... Let's call it interesting results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not delete the local database! Just exclude the admin and local databases from your program output:

```py
if db_name in ['local', 'admin']:
    continue
```

You probably want to also exclude system.indexes from your collection listing.